# How to reopen a plugin-window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am currently taking my first steps in playing around with programming a plugin in python 2.7 for QGIS 1.8. While my plugin does what it should, I would like to make it more userfriendly. At the moment, the user is expected to choose an input- and an output-file, which are then processed. In case the user forgets to choose one (or both) of the files, the plugin is displaying an information window - and then quits completely after the user hits "OK".

```
if src_filepath =="" and dst_filepath =="":
    QMessageBox.information(None, "DEBUG:","Please specify files!")`
```

However, I would rather like to reload the main plugin-window with the "choose file"-dialog. I suspect that the solution is rather easy, but I was not able to invoke this window, so any help is appreciated.
The interface code derives more or less directly from the "Plugin Builder" in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you coded your plugin, but if you encapsuled your dialog inside a class structure, than you could just invoke it again (create a new object).

If you just want to get an "OpenFileDialog" you can create it like this:

```
fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName( self, "title","lastUsedDir", "SHP files (*.shp *.SHP)" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! The solution turned out to be very easy, as I found out with the help of this tutorial: [http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html] (there is also the template of the "Plugin Builder" linked). All I had to do was to end the if-Message with `self.dlg = PluginDialog()
   self.dlg.show()`.